# Using react native for IOS development on Linux

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

I'm curently trying to develop an multi platform app, but i'm using a linux (ubuntu) and I thought that i could just use expo for the development and then just use a mac to build the project.
But it seems that if I want a project that uses for example the camero, a linux isn't gonna cut it.
Am i wrong ?
It seems like I need to use cocoapods, but isn't it just for macOS ?

I'm completly lost on this

Tried using cocoapods thinking it was adapted to both linux and mac but it still need xcode installed, which is strictly for mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was confused, but i was just using expo the wrong way, I now just use the expo SDK that handles automatically the complicated ios stuff, instead of the react-native packages.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).